# How to do string and value sorting at the same time

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort on a calculation result, where there is a String and value, sorting process succeeds, but there is a problem with the string. string does not follow the values ​​that have been in the previous sorting. how to handle it ? getNamaDosen () as String, nilaiDosen as value and getJumlahBakcal() as the amount of data.

Code program :

```
Object[][] data2 = new Object[getJumlahBakcal()][2];
Double [] nilaiDosen = new Double[getJumlahBakcal()];

for(int a=0; a<nilaiDosen.length; a++){
   for(int b=0; b<nilaiDosen.length-1; b++){
      if(nilaiDosen[b]<nilaiDosen[b+1]){
        double temp = nilaiDosen[b];
        nilaiDosen[b] =nilaiDosen[b+1];
        nilaiDosen[b+1] = temp;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < getJumlahBakcal(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
              if (j == 0) {
                  data2[i][j] = getNamaDosen()[i];
              } else if (j == 1) {
                  data2[i][j] = (nilaiDosen[i]);  
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
String[] header = {"Nama Dosen", "Prefensi"};
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data2, header);
analisaVW.getRank().setModel(dtm);
```

Picture illustration :

[image: Picture 1]

Comment: This is a great time to use an object and not parallel arrays.

Comment: @chrylis I agree, but perhaps a TreeMap could also be better, since with a comparator he wouldn't even need a method to sort this information. Plus a map is more intuitive, and we like intuitive code.

Answer (score 0):

> string does not follow the values ​​that have been in the previous sorting

Because, you are only swapping values. So, you want to follow String value as well. Then, you are supposed to swap String at the same time.

I assume, this is where you are swapping values

```
  if(nilaiDosen[b]<nilaiDosen[b+1]){
    double temp = nilaiDosen[b];
    nilaiDosen[b] =nilaiDosen[b+1];
    nilaiDosen[b+1] = temp;
   // include code here to swap Sting value using same index
  }
```

Now, while swapping value, you should also swap the `String` value.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
how to do swap String and value at the same time?

Comment: @kuroashi You haven't shared the code where your String array/collection exists. Then how can I tell you

Comment: String array is in getNamaDosen() function, its value is taken in the database